# cannot convert from 'double' to 'byte'

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm making an application where the user can use the sliders to change the background colour. Here is what I have tried:

```cs
private void Slider_ValueChanged_1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Window1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, Slider1.Value, Slider2.Value, Slider3.Value));
}
```

But instead what happens is this:

> Error  CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'double' to 'byte'

> Error  CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from 'double' to 'byte'

> Error  CS1503  Argument 4: cannot convert from 'double' to 'byte'

I tried converting them to byte:

```cs
Window1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, Convert.ToByte(Slider1.Value), Convert.ToByte(Slider2.Value), Convert.ToByte(Slider3.Value)));
```

But instead it breaks

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Tr4.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you get with the second attempt?

Comment: "it breaks" - what does this mean?

Comment: The error message is clear. `Slider.Value` is a `double`, but `FromArgb` expects four `byte` arguments. This means you would have to cast: `(byte)Silder1.Value`. Make sure the Silder's Maximum is set to 255. Also pass 255 instead of 0 as the first argument, otherwise the Brush will be transparent.

Comment: @KlausGütter sorry to mention that, I have included an image link now, you can see

Comment: @Clemens the slider's maximum is already set to 255

Comment: @Lies I have included an image, you can see it now (i dont have enough reputation to embed it)

Comment: But you would have been able to post the exception text.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the code line `Window1.Background = ...` and check whether `Slider1`, `Slider2`, `Slider3`, and `Window1` are all non-null.

Comment: The ValueChanged event is raised before the Slider1/2/3 members are initialized. Check them for null like `if (Slider1 != null && Slider2 != null && Slider3 != null) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that the value you want to convert is between (0 - 255), by setting the Slider's `Maximum` to 255.

Then try

```
new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(
    255, (byte)Slider1.Value, (byte)Slider2.Value, (byte)Slider3.Value));
```

Comment: Actually what happened at that time the sliders were null. So, I had to add the code suggested by @Clemens so that the code would not execute if the sliders were null.